# Symlink giving "Permission denied"... to root

Tags: linux, file-permissions, symlink

I wrote a simple script to automate creating a symbolic link.

```
#!/pseudo
today = "/tmp/" + date("Y-m-d")
exec("ln -sf " + today + " /tmp/today")
```

Simple enough; get today's date and make a symlink. Ideally run after midnight with `-f` so it just updates it in-place.

This works just fine! ...for my user.

```
xkeeper /tmp$ ls -ltr
drwxrwxrwx  xkeeper   xkeeper   2014-10-21
lrwxrwxrwx  xkeeper   xkeeper   today -> /tmp/2014-10-21/

xkeeper /tmp$ cd today
xkeeper /tmp/today$ cd ..
```

Notice that it works fine, all the permissions are world-readable, everything looks good.

But if someone else wants to use this link (we'll say, root, but any other user has this problem), something very strange happens:

```
root /tmp# cd today
bash: cd: today: Permission denied
```

I am at a complete loss as to why this is. I've also tried creating the links with `ln -s -n -f` (not that "`--no-dereferencing`" is very well-explained), but the same issue appears.

Comment: Note that it works perfectly fine if I create the link itself with root (all other users have access to it), but that doesn't really explain why it doesn't work if created by *other* users.

Comment: What means `#!/pseudo` ?

Comment: Okay, very strange. I tried creating a link in the same way in a temporary folder somewhere in `/var/www/`, and it worked as expected, without permission errors. What in the world.

Comment: @wenzul ...wha? Is there a reference for this? This is the first time I've ever heard such a thing and Googling turns up nothing. It also goes against the traditional role of root both in 40 years of Unix and in computing in general...

Comment: @andlabs Ok I meant this difference behaivor for /tmp amongst others, but may used the wrong words...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since /tmp usually has the sticky bit set, the access to /tmp/today is denied because of `protected_symlinks`. 
You can disable this protection by setting

```
sysctl -w fs.protected_symlinks=0
```

> [protected_symlinks](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/1147961/):
>
> A long-standing class of security issues is the symlink-based
>   time-of-check-time-of-use race, most commonly seen in world-writable
>   directories like /tmp. The common method of exploitation of this flaw
>   is to cross privilege boundaries when following a given symlink (i.e. a
>   root process follows a symlink belonging to another user). For a likely
>   incomplete list of hundreds of examples across the years, please see:
>   http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=/tmp
>
> When set to "0", symlink following behavior is unrestricted.
>
> When set to "1" symlinks are permitted to be followed only when outside
>   a sticky world-writable directory, or when the uid of the symlink and
>   follower match, or when the directory owner matches the symlink's owner.
>
> This protection is based on the restrictions in Openwall and grsecurity.

For further details check [this](http://nerdbynature.de/s9y/?319).

Comment: That makes sense, and explains why it worked in other directories... Also explains why creating a link as root works (because root also owns `/tmp`).

Comment: Excellent answer, this saved me a lot of grief. Thanks!