# Cannot create a symlink readable by another user

Tags: linux, file-permissions, symlink

I issued recently a problem when using symlinks.
I don't understand how to create a symlink to a file that can by read by anyone.

Here is a (simplified) example I ran in docker, from a ubuntu image:

```bash
useradd alice
useradd bob

su -c bash alice
cd /tmp
echo "blabla" > README.txt
chmod 555 README.txt
exit

su -c bash bob
cd /tmp
```

Now, thanks to the permissions I set, `bob` can read `README.txt`:

```
bob:/tmp$ cat README.txt
blabla
bob:/tmp$ ls -l
-r-xr-xr-x 1 alice alice 7 Apr  2 12:11 README.txt
```

Now `bob` creates a symbolic link to `README.txt`:

```
bob:/tmp$ ln -s README.txt link
bob:/tmp$ ls -l
-r-xr-xr-x 1 alice alice  7 Apr  2 12:11 README.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bob   bob   10 Apr  2 12:17 link -> README.txt
bob:/tmp$ cat link
blabla
```

And finally, let's log as `alice` and try to read `bob`'s symlink:

**EDIT**: here I execute the command as `alice` (and not `bob`, I did a mistake in the original post)

```
alice:/tmp$ ls -l
-r-xr-xr-x 1 alice alice  7 Apr  2 12:26 README.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bob   bob   10 Apr  2 12:29 link -> README.txt
alice:/tmp$ cat link
cat: link: Permission denied
```

I don't understand why I can't read this symlink, because I have all the rights required to read `README.txt` and `link` itself.
I created a docker image if you want to hack a bit around with my problem, it's available [here](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/atxr/symlink-test/general)
You just have to pull and run the image:

```bash
docker run -it atxr/symlink-test:latest /bin/bash
```

I tried to search in the symlink documentation, and found out that its permissions should be the same than the actual path it points to.
I also paid attention to the folder rights (the `x`/`X` permission), `/tmp` in this case, to see if `alice` is actually able to resolve the path.

I'm really confused about this behavior and wonder how can I create a symlink to a file that can be read by anyone else.

Comment: I can't reproduce. `docker run -ti ubuntu bash -xeuc 'useradd alice; useradd bob; su -c "set -xeu && cd /tmp && echo blabla > README.txt && chmod 555 README.txt" alice; su -c "set -xeu && cd /tmp && ls -l && ln -s README.txt link && cat link" bob'` works fine.

Comment: Yes, until there no problem. The issue comes just after, when `alice` tries to read `bob`'s link. I just noticed the username was wrong at this point in my example, I edited my post, sorry for this

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496352/symlink-giving-permission-denied-to-root answer your question?